# Enforce type of a property that is an array after extending some interfaces

Tags: typescript

Given an enum:

```js
enum Actions {
    INCREASE_BRIGHTNESS = 'INCREASE_BRIGHTNESS',
    DECREASE_BRIGHTNESS = 'DECREASE_BRIGHTNESS',
    TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE'
}
```

And two interfaces `Dimmable` and `Togglable` which both have property `actions` of type tuple:

```js
interface Dimmable {
    minBrightness: number;
    maxBrightness: number;
    actions: [ Actions.INCREASE_BRIGHTNESS, Actions.DECREASE_BRIGHTNESS ]
}

interface Togglable {
    actions: [ Actions.TOGGLE ]
}
```

I would like to have an interface `MyDevice` that extends `Dimmable` and `Togglable`:

```js
interface MyDevice extends Dimmable, Togglable {}
```

Because the types of `actions` in interfaces `Togglable` and `Dimmable` are not the same, I got the error:

`Interface 'MyDevice' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Dimmable' and 'Togglable'.
  Named property 'actions' of types 'Dimmable' and 'Togglable' are not identical.`

So I ommited `actions` in `Dimmable` and `Togglable` when extending them and the error is gone:

```js
interface MyDevice extends Omit<Dimmable, 'actions'>, Omit<Togglable, 'actions'> {};
```

But what I really want is to have property `actions` in `MyDevice` in which the type becomes like below:

```js
interface MyDevice extends Omit<Dimmable, 'actions'>, Omit<Togglable, 'actions'> {
    actions: [ // <-- How to type actions from Dimmable and Togglable so it  will be a tuple like this ???
        Actions.INCREASE_BRIGHTNESS,
        Actions.DECREASE_BRIGHTNESS,
        Actions.TOGGLE
    ]
};
```

Is that possible ? is there a way to get the type of `actions` in `MyDevice` from types of `actions` in `Dimmable` and `Togglable` ?

Comment: Related https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26058

Comment: There're some ugly workarounds, not sure you want get there..

Comment: Forcing TypeScript to concatenate tuple types is generally unpleasant.  Do you really care about order and quantity of elements in the interface?  Would `Array<Dimmable['actions'][number] | Togglable['actions'][number]>` work well enough for you?

Comment: @jcalz I don't care about order but quantity is important for me